# Joomla, 500 ошибка в админке, на странице модулей

Tags: php, xml, joomla, cms, joomla3

При переносе сайта с локалки на хостинг, появилась непонятная проблема, при открытии страницы в админ-панели модулей, появляется ошибка

> 500 Joomla\CMS\Form\Form::getInstance() could not load file

Логи показывают что проблема в com_modules:

> `213.21.62.143 - - [15/Aug/2019:15:17:49 +0300] "GET /administrator/index.php?option=com_modules HTTP/1.0" 500 4329`

Проверяла все файлы в этой папке, перезаливала новые, ничего не помогает.

Может кто то сталкивался с такой проблемой, как решали?

Comment: Я бы смотрел права на файлы. И думал бы о переходе на WP

Comment: Права везде 777, а wp не понравился)

Comment: `Проверяла все файлы в этой папке`  и что показала проверка, файл такой есть ?

Comment: @zalex ну конечно, я же с исходной джумлы папку перезаливала.

Comment: Если современная  джумла умеет в автозагрузку, я бы на вашем месте проверил бы как раз файл автозагрузки. Возможно его нужно перегенерить, в случае если composer используется, в чем я конечно сомневаюсь, однако мы же ищем возможные варианты решения проблемы. p.s. Посмотрел репозиторий в гитхабе, действительно используется composer .

Comment: Вот что то похожее на вашу проблему https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=710&t=826472

Пишут в конце  вот что 

    add:
        libxml_disable_entity_loader(false);
    in:
        /libraries/joomla/language/language.php
    before:
        $xml = simplexml_load_file($path); (around line 1382)

Comment: @zalex да, я видела это, прежде чем сюда писать, я облазила весь интернет, в моей версии джумла 3.9.1, в пути /libraries/joomla/language/ нет папки language :)

Comment: Попробуйте в файле configuration.php  заменить свойство public $error_reporting = 'default'; (или что там у вас вместо default) например на development  , возможно вы увидите что то еще из за чего ошибка.

Comment: @zalex изменила, ничего не поменялось(

Comment: А в php.ini возмоно нужно выставить еще
 display_errors = On
error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT

Comment: @zalex у меня на хостинге нельзя менять php.ini :)